При добавлении Cookie в код возникает ошибка 500
Создала проект в Intellij Idea Ultimate с
Generations: JavaEE 
Template: Web Application 
Language: Java 
Build System: Maven 
Specifications: Web profile 
Создала страницу сервлета и index.jsp, всё работало. Но после добавления в код cookie при запуске выдает ошибку:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\a_sen\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2024.1\tomcat\8bfcd653-8989-4d5a-9f06- 1e8b34e35303\work\Catalina\localhost\Ex2\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java] Only a type can be imported. jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie resolves to a package

Надеюсь на вашу помощь
Код:
Сервлет:
package servlets;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

@WebServlet( urlPatterns = "/degree_elements")
public class MassIndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8; pageEncoding=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        String arrayInput = request.getParameter("array");
        String[] array = arrayInput.split(",");
        String LastIndexArray = null;
        try
        {
            writer.println("<h4>Элементы:</h4>");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                if ((i & (i - 1)) == 0 && i != 0)
                {
                    writer.println("<li>" + array[i].trim() + "</li>");
                    LastIndexArray+=array[i].trim()+",";
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        { writer.close();
            if (LastIndexArray == null)
            {
                LastIndexArray ="нет";
            }
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("LastIndexArray", LastIndexArray);
            cookie.setMaxAge(-1);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}

index.jsp
<%@ page import="jakarta.servlet.http.Cookie" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Пользовательская форма</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="degree_elements" method="POST">
    Введите массив элементов: <input  name="array"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
<br><br>
Элементы прошлого запроса:

<ul>
    <%
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                if ("LastIndexArray".equals(cookie.getName())) { %>
    <li><%= cookie.getValue() %></li>
    <%

            }
        }
    }
    else {
    %>
    нет
    <%}%>
</ul>
</body>
</html>

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>servlets</groupId>
  <artifactId>Ex2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Ex2</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>9.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
      </plugin>    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

web.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
</web-app>

